# Edit a merge to include "--no-ff"

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

My `git` workflow include to use `no-ff` flag when merging `hotfix`, `issue` and `feature` branches so we have a better picture of the project by being able to see each commit.

I just merged a branch and forgot to add the "--no-ff" flag. I'm actually using [SourceTree](https://www.atlassian.com/software/sourcetree/overview), how can I edit said commit so that it behaves as if I hadn't forgotted to add the flag? If possible, explain how to do this on `SourceTree` client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reset the branch you merged into back to where it was before. Then you can remake the merge commit using `--no-ff`.

To make sure you don't accidentally make a fast forward commit next time, you can change the preferences:

- Open the *Preferences* dialog
- Navigate to the *Git* tab
- Ensure that the "Do not fast-forward when merging" option is enabled.

To undo the fast forward merge you need to make a hard reset:

- Select the commit where the branch used to be in the commit list
- Right click and select *Reset [branch name] to this commit*
- Choose the hard reset option.

Then you can remake the merge commit.